# Checking if an element is generated in a particular function

Tags: python, math, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I have a function i.e

> f(n) = (2* f(n-1)) - (2* f(n-2))
>   Where f(0)=0 and f(1) = 1

I have a list (num_list). How do I check if the elements of num_list has been generated by the function f(n). Where n>1.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this for arbitrary functions.

Comment: Only method I can think of is a brute force approach.

Comment: That's true, but then what about the time complexity , if n=10^8 , the recursive function would take years to compute it.

Comment: This is an example of a [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence).

Answer (score 3):

This is a linear recurrence relation, so f(n) can be written in a closed form. The recurrence relation is:

> f(n + 2) − 2f(n + 1) + 2f(n) = 0

Since the left-hand side is linear and the right-hand side is zero, this is a simpler form of the more general problem of solving a linear recurrence relation: we don't need to find a "particular solution" to satisfy the right-hand side, just the "general solution" is enough.

The general solution can be found by solving the equation f(n) = x<sup>n</sup> to find the values of x satisfying the recurrence relation. By substituting and simplifying, we get the quadratic equation:

> x<sup>2</sup> − 2x + 2 = 0

The solutions to this equation are the complex numbers x = 1 + i and x = 1 − i where i is the [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number). By linearity, it follows that any function of the form

> f(n) = a (1 + i)<sup>n</sup> + b (1 − i)<sup>n</sup>

is a solution; by substituting the boundary conditions f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1 we get a = −i/2 and b = i/2. So, the closed form expression for f(n) is:

> f(n) = (i/2) ((1 − i)<sup>n</sup> − (1 + i)<sup>n</sup>)

This can be rewritten by applying [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), since we know f(n) is always a real number:

> f(n) = (−1/2) (√2)<sup>n</sup> Im (e<sup>−nπ/4</sup> − e<sup>nπ/4</sup>) = (√2)<sup>n</sup> sin(nπ/4)

The expression sin(nπ/4) is the sequence `[0, 1/√2, 1, 1/√2, 0, −1/√2, −1, −1/√2, ...]`, which repeats with period 8. It follows that for each natural number k, the sequence takes the values:

- f(8k) = f(8k + 4) = 0
- f(8k + 1) = 2<sup>4k</sup>
- f(8k + 2) = f(8k + 3) = 2<sup>4k + 1</sup>
- f(8k + 5) = −2<sup>4k + 2</sup>
- f(8k + 6) = f(8k + 7) = −2<sup>4k + 3</sup>

Therefore, the function generates a number if and only if it is of one of these forms.

Answer (score 2):

You could analyze the function itself rather than use a brute force approach. Looking at wolfram, there should be some condition to check if it exists. Looking at the first 13 values:

> [0,1,2,2,0,-4,-8,-8,0,16,32,32,0]

I guess if you look at

> log2(abs(f(n))) -> [-,0,1,1,2,3,3,-,4,5,5,-]
>
> Simplified logically to [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5] ignoring the 0s.

So we have pattern. I think this is solvable in a manner where:

So if the sqrt of abs(num) is an integer. Its possible to be part of the pattern. 
We then need a check for the values if it should be negative or positive.

Breaking down farther:
positive values [0,1,1,4,5,5,8,9,9,...]
Negative values [2,3,3,6,7,7,10,11,11...]

We can then check if n % 4 == 0 or (n-1)%4 == 0.
If that is true and the original value is positive -> than yes it was made from f(n)
If false and original value is negative -> also made from f(n)

otherwise it wasnt.

```
import numpy as np
def test(x):
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return True
    if x == -1 or x == -2:
        return False
    val = np.log2(abs(x))
    if val%1==0:
        if(val%4 == 0 or (val-1)%4==0) and x >0:
            return True
        elif (val%4!=0 and (val-1)%4 != 0) and x <0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

I give no guarantees that my math is correct. Tested it and seems to be working. There may be some math bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Sympy's rsolve can be used to find a general formula for a recursion.

```py
from sympy import rsolve, Function, log
from sympy.abc import n

f = Function('f', real=True)
T = f(n) -   (2* f(n-1) - 2* f(n-2))
s = rsolve(T, f(n), {f(0): 0, f(1): 1})
print ("solution for n:", s)
'''I*((1 - I)**n - (1 + I)**n)/2'''

for k in range(10):
    print(k, s.subs(n, k).simplify())
```

For this particular equation, the solution involves pesky imaginary numbers, and sympy has a hard time simplifying the equation for large n. For simpler equations, either `s.subs(n, k).simplify()` or `s.subs(n, k).evalf()` should give an adequate answer even for large n.

As noted by @JasonChia, and given the fact that you are only interested in knowing whether a number can be generated or not, one could also simply look at the sequence:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, -4, -8, -8, 0, 16, 32, 32, 0, -64, -128, -128, 0, 256, 512, 512, 0, -1024, -2048, -2048, 0, 4096, 8192, 8192, 0, ...]
```

All powers of 2, together with 0, appear but either as positive or as negative number. The negative numbers are of the form 2<sup>k</sup> when `k mod 4` equal to 2 or 3. And write some function as:

```py
def is_in_the_squence(x):
    if not isinstance(x, int):
        return False
    elif x == 0:
        return True
    else:
        k = 0
        while x != 1 and x != -1:
            k += 1
            if x % 2 != 0:
                return False
            x //= 2
        return ( x == -1 and k % 4 >= 2) or ( x == 1 and k % 4 < 2)
```

Comment: There's a simpler way to test if a non-zero number is a power of 2; `(x & (x-1)) == 0`. So you can test this for `abs(x)` and then do the sign test separately.